# Multiple RKRequestDescriptors with same RKRequestMethod

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have two routes:

**POST** `/food.json`

Request body:`{"food": {"name":"Banana", color:"yellow"}}`

Request Descriptor:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *createRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:createMapping 
    objectClass:[Food class] 
    rootKeyPath:@"food" 
    method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

--

**POST** `/food/batch.json`

Request body: `{"foods": [{"name":"Banana", color:"yellow"}, {"name":"Apple", "color":"red" }]}`

Request Descriptor:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *batchRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:createMapping 
     objectClass:[Food class] 
     rootKeyPath:@"foods" 
     method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

--

The problem I am running into is the that the create and batch request both use **POST** request methods, so if I try to add them both as request descriptors, I get:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot add request descriptor: An existing descriptor is already registered for the class 'Food' and HTTP method'(POST)'.'`

Is there a conditional for request descriptors where I can say:

Use the `batchRequestDescriptor` for path `/food/batch` and use the createRequestDescriptor for the `/food` path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you would use named routes (`RKRoute` Instances), and when you want to make a POST you would use `requestWithPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:` and then create your operation from the route.

It's more common to see your situation for GET and that's why `getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure:` exists, but you will need to do a little more work (and/or create your own convenience method).

Comment: Ah, I was hoping there was a RKRequestDescriptor for specific paths :(